# how to add optional field to a class manually in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

In my .proto I have some messages that have optional fields. There is no native protogen for Debian so I don't have one to experiment with (too lazy to compile it myself :).

Could you tell me how to implement an optional field in a class in C#? I would like to have a function or whatever that idicate the field is set (in C++ I have something like hasfoo() ). In examples I found in the internet there is nothing like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It supports a number of patterns here, to help transition from other serializers. And note that there are options in the protobuf-net `protogen` to include such members for you automatically.

Firstly, anything `null` is omitted; this includes both `null` references and `Nullable<T>` for structs. So:

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
public int? A {get;set;}
```

will behave.

Another option is default values; using .NET conventions:

```
[ProtoMember(2), DefaultValue(17)]
public int B {get;set;}
```

no values of 17 will be serialized.

For more explicit control, the `ShouldSerialize*` pattern (from `XmlSerializer`) and the `*Specified` pattern (from `DataContractSerializer`) are observed, so you can do:

```
[ProtoMember(3)]
public string C {get;set;}

public bool ShouldSerializeC() { /* return true to serialize */ }
```

and

```
[ProtoMember(4)]
public string D {get;set;}

public bool DSpecified {get;set;} /* return true to serialize */
```

These can be public or private (unless you are generating a standalone serialization assembly, which requires public).

If your main classes are coming from code-gen, then a `partial class` is an ideal extension point, i.e.

```
partial class SomeType {
    /* extra stuff here */
}
```

since you can add that in a separate code file.

Comment: Why is this so difficult? I simply want to know if the client has specified a null or not. If the field is explicitly set to null, then I want the web service to act on it (by setting the corresponding field to null in the database). If the client hasn't explicitly specified a null, then I don't want to take any action. The client doesn't always have the entire universe of fields that the database has, so often it will only change the fields that the user is interested in changing, without wanting to update the entire record. This often includes explicitly setting things to null.

Comment: "Firstly, anything null is omitted" Why??? Why do you think this is a value that can be assumed? What if the value of the DefaultAttribute for an "int?" is 0? That would make null an explicit value that needs to be serialized, because nothing in the stream would mean the default, which is 0!

Comment: @QuarkSoup because the protobuf wire specification has no concept of null and no way of encoding "explicitly missing"; later versions of protobuf-net have optional [null wrapper](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net/nullwrappers) support, which can help mitigate this

Comment: How? I've pulled apart the code. Yes, you can transmit a null in an FloatValue. How do you detect, on the other side of the wire, that this value has been set by the client? With the 'optional' keyword on an Int32, there's a bit mask that provides the 'HasX' property to the server.  How do I force the same functionality from the Int32Value?

Comment: @QuarkSoup IIRC `optional int32 foo = 1;` should map to `[ProtoMember(1)] public int? Foo {get;set;}`; if you're comparing to `.google.protobuf.Int32Value`, then you'd use `[ProtoMember(1), NullWrappedValue] public int? Foo {get;set;}`

Comment: I've got more than 500 fields on a data structure given to us by a vendor. I want to set just one of those fields to null on the database that is accessed through the Web Service.  I've seen your comments about the 'NullWrappedValue' and pulled apart the code. I can find no place on the server-side code that provides the functionality of 'optional' (e.g. HasX). How do you detect, on the server, if this 'wrapped' field was explicilty set to null by the client?

Comment: @QuarkSoup to clarify: you want to be able to distinguish an explicitly assigned null from an implicit non-assigned null? That's trickier - nothing in the regular protocol would support that without hackery. I can think of simple-ish ways to hack it in, but it would not be backwards data compatible - do you need that too? The other option I can think of requires a bunch of extra flag fields (only in the "explicit null" case) - are we allowed to add such? Happy to explore options, but this is a little outside the default :p

Comment: Yes, think of the use case: how do you explicitly set a database value to 'null'? This is not a unique problem. I simply want the same functionality I get with the 'optional' attribute on an int32 in proto3, but on an Int32Value. I don't understand why it's so difficult.

Comment: @quarksoup Neither `optional int32` nor `Int32Value` can distinguish between implicit null and explicit null - and in both cases it literally sends nothing (zero bytes) for the non-assigned case. But yes, in protobuf-net you can handle `optional int32` and `Int32Value` scenarios and detect the non-assigned case distinct to the assigned case. You just can't tell explicitly non-assigned from implicitly non-assigned, because that's not a scenario that anyone usually needs. Reading between the lines, it sounds like you want "no value" to mean "no change" in the context of DB updates - is that...

Comment: ...right? If so, indeed, you won't also be able to have  "no value" mean "explicitly wipe this value" - we'd need to add a flag somewhere for that. I'll happily help you do that, but it may be too long for SO comments! Maybe ping me on email or GitHub.

Comment: Sure. I was actually digging into the code and I had this thought: Why not make the highest bit of the 'field #' into a 'IsNull' bit or a 'HasExplicitDefault' bit? Now, that would leave you with just 32,768 fields, but I would argue that the added functionality is worth the inconvenience. Also, on a null or default, you would only take up the space for (IsNull + Field) in the buffer. That is, there's no need to send a value.